# i have class " my_string ". I overloaded operator " == ", but it doesnt work with pointers (my_string*)

Tags: c++, class, comparison, operator-overloading

i overloaded operator== and it doesnt work with pointers

```
class my_string { 

    private:

        char* _ch;
        int _length;

    public:
                ...
                ...
        bool operator ==(const my_string& right) {

            if (this->_length == right._length) {

                for (int i = 0; i < this->_length; i++) {
                    if (_ch[i] != right._ch[i]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }

            else
                return false;
            return true;

        }
};

int main(){

my_string* f = "hello";

my_string* g = "hello";

if(f==g){

   cout<<"done";

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just use `my_string f = "hello";` and `my_string g = "hello";`. Why do you think you need pointers there?

Comment: `my_string* f = "hello";` is an invalid initialization to begin with. It makes `f` point to the first character of the array containing the string `"hello"`. It does ***not*** create a new `my_string` object.

Comment: And the comparison `f==g` is comparing the *pointers*, not calling any overloaded functions of objects they might point to.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

First of all, there is a difference when you call `f == g` if the type is `string` or `string*`. If the type is `string*` you are not actually comparing the strings, but instead you are comparing the pointers themselves (which rarely makes sense). If the type is `string*`, you would need to use `*f == *g` to compare them (`*` dereferences the pointers and gives you the actual object that is pointed to).

In addition to that, pointers are not required here and the code `my_string* f = "hello"` should not compile.
If you wanted a pointer to your string, you would need to use

```
my_string str = "hello";
my_string* ptr = &str;
```

But again, I do not see why you would use pointers here.

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please mark the answer as solved.